# How to access Dancer2's session object?

Tags: perl, session, dancer

I'm using Dancer2 and the YAML session engine for my web app.
My `config.yml` contains

```
engines:
  session:
    YAML:
      ...
      cookie_duration: 5 minutes
      ...
```

I'd like to display something like *"Your session expires in X minutes"*.

How can I access this value, i.e. how can I access the `$session` object in my routes?

With the DSL keyword `session` I can only set and get 
arbitrary values, like `session username => 'Bob';` and `$username = session('username');` etc.

Note that I'm not interested in getting the configuration value (`settings('engines')->{session}{YAML}{cookie_duration}`) because that's a string I'd had to parse and it depends on YAML being my session engine. I'd like to access `$session->session_duration`.

Comment: In theory you should do `session->expires`, as `session` just returns the session object when it's used like that. However, in my test that returned `undef`. But I didn't have a full config and it's possible I did something wrong. If you do `p session` via `Data::Printer` you'll see that the Dancer2::Core::Session object that `session` returns has a method `expires`. The `cookie_duration` is not the expiry of the session on the server. See https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Session#expires

Comment: Hey, cool! That's exactly the solution. In my configuration `session->expires` returns 1514648770 (which is `now + 6 months`, the value I currently have configured as `cookie_duration`). Perfect. My problem was that I couldn't figure out how to access that value and/or convert `session()` to a `$session`. If you write a (short) answer, I'll overwhelm it with upvotes. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the session object back when you call `session` without any arguments. Feel free to assign it to a `$session` variable if that makes it easier to read. To get the expiration time, use [the `expires` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Session#expires).

```
my $session = session;
warn $session->expires;
```

Or simpler:

```
warn session->expires;
```